# How can I add custom TTF font in my React Native project?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fonts

I'm trying to add custom TTF font to my react native project, I've followed articles :

1) I've create a folder in my root and putted vincHand.ttf in that :

```
projectName/assets/fonts/vincHand.ttf
```

2) I've executed this command :

```
react-native link
```

And then I've checked and font has transferred to android path right

3) I've uninstalled the app in the Genymotion and again I've executed this command :

```
react-native run-android
```

But after fontFamily: 'vincHand' that text is shown with default font ...

Consider it, I've downloaded this font from here :

https://www.dafont.com/vinchand.font

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure two things:

The first thing is you already defined this in package.json

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
},
```

React-Native will automatically copy the font to `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`

The second thing is defining this in Info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>vincHand.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Then run `react-native link`

For usage case:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcome: {
    fontFamily: "vincHand",
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: I see and I've did these steps ! and as you know Info.plist is only for iOS and I'm using Android. But after these steps that problem is remains ....

Answer (score 0):

1. Create assets folder in the root folder of your project.
2. Create fonts folder inside the assets folder.
3. Paste all the fonts inside the fonts folder.
4. Add the below mentioned code inside the package.json file.
5. Run the below mentioned Command

> react-native link

6. Fonts will get installed on both the platforms(IOS and Android).

> ```
> "rnpm": {
>     "assets": [
>     "./assets/fonts/"
>     ]
> },
> ```

Comment: Can you re-check the folder names and path defined in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Both ios & android (without expo):

1 - create a folder called "assets", inside it create "fonts" folder and put all your ttf files inside it.

2 - create a file in the root called: `react-native.config.js` and put insdie it :

```
        module.exports = {
                project: {
                        ios: {},
                        android: {}
                },
                assets: ['./assets/fonts']
        };
```

3 - run this command: `npx react-native link`